# Compilation Errors in running objective c code in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

//--------@interface section--------

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
   int numerator;
   int denominator;
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(void) print;

@end

//-------@implementation section-------

@implementation Fraction;

//getters

-(int) numerator {
    return numerator;
}

-(int) denominator {
    return denominator;
}

//setters

-(void) setNumerator: (int) num {
    numerator = num;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) denom {   
    denominator = denom;
}

//other

-(void) print {
    printf("The value of the fraction is %i/%i\n", numerator, denominator);
}

@end


//---------program section---------

int main(void) {
    Fraction *myFract;

    myFract = [Fraction new];

    [myFract setNumerator: 1];
    [myFract setDenominator: 3];

    printf("The numerator is %i, and the denominator is %i\n", 
                [myFract numerator], [myFract denominator]);
    [myFract print];

    [myFract free];

    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it

```
$gcc -framework Foundation p10.m
```

I got ff. errors:

```
Program19_2.m: In function ‘main’:
Program19_2.m:55:2: warning: ‘Fraction’ may not respond to ‘+new’ [enabled by default] 
Program19_2.m:55:2: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature [enabled by
default]
Program19_2.m:55:2: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept [enabled by
default]
Program19_2.m:55:2: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.) [enabled by default]
Program19_2.m:64:2: warning: ‘Fraction’ may not respond to ‘-free’ [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccVRbEBu.o: In function `main':
Program19_2.m:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `objc_get_class'
Program19_2.m:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
Program19_2.m:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
Program19_2.m:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
Program19_2.m:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
Program19_2.m:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/tmp/ccVRbEBu.o:Program19_2.m:(.text+0x14e): more undefined references to
`objc_msg_lookup' follow
/tmp/ccVRbEBu.o: In function `__objc_gnu_init':
Program19_2.m:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `__objc_exec_class'
/tmp/ccVRbEBu.o:(.data+0x148): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_Object'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just copied the code from a textbook. Change the libraries I import because they are (Object.h) now deprecated. I wonder why it doesn't run. Is there something wrong with the way I compile the program?

Comment: You mean *Compilation Error* right?  Your title suggests the language is broken, when the error is, in fact, wholly yours.

Comment: what is the `Object` exactly where you inherited your class from? is it an kind of `NSObject`? the `NSObject` _has_ the `+new` method, but we don't know anything about the `Object`, I think.

Comment: so how do I compile this thing? is gcc p10.m enough? My first assumption is that the book might just a topographical error.

Comment: I think gcc is not including `Object`

Comment: @Ralf17 Does `Object` inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: tried both Object and NSObject as well but it doesn't work

Comment: I've found a little info about the `<objc/Object.h>`, **it has been deprecated since October of 2007**. it was almost 6 years ago. how new the textbook do you have...?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? Just calling `gcc` wouldn't be enough as it's not linking the `Object` library as well.

Comment: I modified the question so that everyone who viewed this will have a clear idea about the things that I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start would be installing clang.. should be at least 3.2 (I use trunk as it seems to have less problem with ObjC++), make it use libobjc that come with GNUstep aka GNUstep runtime, not GCC. If you don't need GCC for anything else, uninstall GCC and any libobjc that came with it, just use clang. And it's a good idea to build project with GNUstep+GNUmakefile, There are tutorials you can google for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that your book predates modern Objective-C (i.e. Objective-C 2.0).

The `Object` class has been around for decades but since the introduction of the NeXTSTEP framework, in a way it has become obsolete. It is very rare to write Objective-C without the NeXTSTEP framework (whether it is Apple's Foundation or GNU's GNUstep).

Forget learning about `Object`. Although your book may be able to teach you some fundamentals of Objective-C, it won't teach you about any of the latest advancements in the language that truly change how you program with it (including blocks, properties, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If gcc couldn't find Object.h, it would give an error indicating that. The problem is that Apple removed most of the methods from `Object.h` (or at least the interface for it) in Objective-C 2.0.

**`The main reason your program is giving these errors is that gcc is not including the Object class.`**

Instead, you should subclass NSObject and include the Foundation framework.

Comment: I replaced the line #import <objc/Object.h> with <Foundation/Foundation.h> and @interface Fraction: NSObject but the compiler says that there is no Foundation/Foundation.h

Comment: Don't know then..you should google about using gcc for objective c

Comment: @Ralf17: When you compile, you have to use `gcc -framework Foundation src.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alloc` and then  `init` to initialize ,to free a memory use `release`

Also note declared as

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
```

implemented as

//setters

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int) num 
-(void) setDenominator: (int) denom
```

Use

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
    numerator = num;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {   
    denominator = denom;
}
```

Comment: Those methods are not declared on `Object`. `Object` is an antiquated root class that used to be defined by the runtime itself rather than a framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
Program19_2.m:55:2: warning: ‘Fraction’ may not respond to ‘+new’ [enabled by default]
```

I don't understand that error.  I just looked at `/usr/include/objc/Object.h` and the interface definitely has `new` in it.  The only odd thing is that `Object` is `#define`ed out if you are using Objective-C 2.0, but then you should get an error that the interface doesn't exist at all.  Maybe some other header has a forward declaration of `Object`.  Try compiling with the `-E` flag to see what the result of preprocessing is.

```
am19_2.m:64:2: warning: ‘Fraction’ may not respond to ‘-free’ [enabled by default]
```

This is caused by the same issue as the first error.

```
Program19_2.m:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `objc_get_class'
```

All of the errors of this form are caused by you not linking the program against the Objective-C runtime.  You can probably get rid of them this way:

```
gcc p10.m  -lobjc
```

The above is all very well, but the real problem is that your text book is many years out of date.  I first started using Objective-C more than 10 years ago and already nobody was using `Object` as a base class.  You need to find a book that uses the classes from Foundation and Cocoa - the ones that begin `NS`.